# Stateful widget in listview and reloading leads to error

Tags: android, listview, flutter, statefulwidget

When I make a ListView with an array of stateless widgets I get no errors, everything works perfectly. However when I put Stateful widgets into the array and rerender the widget by scrolling it so it ends outside of the view then I get errors.

I tried it on ListView and ListView.builder and there seems to be no difference. I thought the problem was with the text so I tried to remove all Text constructors but there was no difference. The widget does initialize and dispose but does not reinitialize.

```
class CustomSettingsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    static const String routeName = "/settings";

    @override
    CustomSettingsScreenState createState() =>CustomSettingsScreenState();
}

class CustomSettingsScreenState extends State<CustomSettingsScreen> {
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
    }

final listElements = {
    Divider(height: 500),
    VibrateStartRecordingEnablePreference(
        preferenceKey: PreferenceKeys.keyVibrateStartRecordingEnable,
    ),
    Divider(height: 500),
    Divider(height: 500),
    Divider(height: 500),
    Divider(height: 500),
    };
```

};

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Settings"),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listElements.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return listElements.elementAt(index);
        },
    ),);
    }
}

class VibrateStartRecordingEnablePreference extends StatefulWidget {
    VibrateStartRecordingEnablePreference({
    Key key,
    @required this.preferenceKey,
});

final preferenceKey;

final _VibrateStartRecordingEnablePreferenceState
  _vibrateStartRecordingEnablePreferenceState =
  new _VibrateStartRecordingEnablePreferenceState();

@override
_VibrateStartRecordingEnablePreferenceState createState() =>
    _vibrateStartRecordingEnablePreferenceState;
}

class _VibrateStartRecordingEnablePreferenceState extends State<VibrateStartRecordingEnablePreference> {
    String _title = "Vibrate at the start of recording";
    String _subtitleOn = "Vibrates once upon start of recording";
    String _subtitleOff = "Will not vibrate at start";
    bool _value = true;

String _getSubtitle() {
    if (_value)
        return _subtitleOn;
    else
      return _subtitleOff;
}

void _updateValue(bool value) {
    Settings().save(widget.preferenceKey, value);
    setState(() {
      _value = value;
    });
}

@override
void initState() {
    //Update the values and text
    Settings().getBool(widget.preferenceKey, true).then((value) {
        setState(() {
        _value = value;
      });
    });

    super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SwitchListTile(
        secondary: const Icon(Icons.vibration),
        title: Text("$_title"),
        subtitle: Text(_getSubtitle()),
        value: _value,
        onChanged: (value) {
            _updateValue(value);
        },
    );
    }
}
```

The error in debugger

```
The following assertion was thrown building         NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:     'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4006 pos         
12: '_state._widget == null': is not true.
```

Here is a video of what is happening.
https://webm.red/6ZTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_vibrateStartRecordingEnablePreferenceState` is stored inside `VibrateStartRecordingEnablePreference` which is wrong. 
Framework tries to attach state instance to widget, but state is already attached to one. So it leads to exception.

You have to return a new instance of state every time when `createState()` is called in StatefulWidget

Comment: How would I be able to call member functions of the state if I can't access them through the stateful widget?

Comment: Well, you could create a global key for a state like this `final key = GlobalKey<_VibrateStartRecordingEnablePreferenceState>();`, store it somewhere higher in widget tree and pass it to widget constructor. Don't forget to update constructor of `VibrateStartRecordingEnablePreference` with calling `: super(key: key)`. Then you will be able to access `key.currentState.someMethod()`.  

However I would question such design. There are not so many cases when calling methods of state outside of it is truly required.